# Console doesn't print key value

Tags: javascript, json

This is my part of the JSON code. `pants` would be the "children" key of `MALE` if selected `gender` is `male`, while it would be children key of `FEMALE` if selected `gender` is `female`.

```js
var data = {
  "gender": "male",
  "myFilter": {
    "MALE": {
      "pants": ["33", "34"]
    },
    "FEMALE": {}
  }
}

console.log(myFilter.data[gender.value].pants[0]);
```

How do I do a clean work to do the job? I'd simply want to use the selected gender not as a key, but as a variable key. I tried everything but nothing works.

`data` is the full JSON payload.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a variable key' than 'a key'?

Comment: @Pengson I guess he means dynamic key depends on the gender

Comment: @Pengson ^ this

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question, with an ACTUAL example? I updated it, feel free to make it more correct to fit your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "gender": "male",
  "myFilter": {
    "MALE": {
      "pants": ["33", "34"]
    },
    "FEMALE": {}
  }
}
var pants = data.myFilter[data.gender.toUpperCase()].pants;
for(var i=0; i<pants.length; i++){
 console.log(pants[i])
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that makes sense and has a working example...

Answer (score 1):

```
data.gender.toLowerCase() === 'male' 
  ? data.myFilter.MALE.pants[0]
  : data.myFilter.FEMALE.pants[0]
```

For Dynamic Keys

```
data.myFilter.[data.gender.toUpperCase()].pants[0]
```

Comment: Well, thanks but this is not really the point of what I'm asking.

Comment: What do you mean my variable key. You can use [] for dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

IF your object is like this.

```
data: {
  "gender": "male",
  "myFilter": {
       "MALE": {
           "pants": ["33", "34"]
       },
       "FEMALE": {}
   },
}
```

Then (gender value is maybe "MALE" or "FEMALE")

```
Console.log(data.myFilter[gender.value].pants[0]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: That is an invalid console print statement. This is not C#, check your syntax....

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

```js
console.log(data.myFilter[data.gender.toUpperCase()]["pants"][0]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me